# Do "who" questions not get auxiliary verb?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, do-support, question-words

Normally, if I want to build a question about someone's verb, then I know the following formula.

1. building of **statement**.
2. **Adding auxiliary verb** in the beginning of the sentence and make it question.
3. **adding WH question** **word** before the auxiliary verb

For example:

> It makes him happy > **Does** it make him happy? > **What does** make
>   him happy?

Now my question is why do when we use the verb "weights" then we don't use the auxiliary verb in the 3rd stage (wh question word):

> He weights 80 kg > **Does** he weights 80 kg? > **Who weights** 80 kg?

I found just a few results for: "who does weights" and a pretty much of them are not relevant. Maybe it's not about the word "weights" but it's about the wh question "who" that behaves as exceptional for the mentioned formula, and I see it a lot in the spoken language, but I don't have enough knowledge to say it confidently.

Comment: What P.E. Dant said.  Try searching for "Who **weighs** ..?" and you should get a much happier result.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Better check your dictionary again. *Weight* can most definitely be used as a verb in English.

Comment: @Robusto - It can, but it's not what the OP means in this case.

Comment: "Weight" is a verb in English, but it means _to add weight,_  and it's transitive. The intransitive verb you are trying to use here is **weigh.**

Comment: @Stangdon: Not to be pedantic about it, but I was only responding to P.E. Dant's assertion, since deleted for obvious reasons, that *weight* is not a verb in English. He misspoke, I challenged, and now the matter has gone on too long. I intended to delete my comment once he did his, but now the chain has legs ...